# Is the projection of a pseudoconvex domain necessarily pseudoconvex?

Tags: several-complex-variables

Is the projection of a pseudoconvex domain necessarily pseudoconvex?

I think that it is not necessarily true, but I cannot come up with an example.

Answer (score 4):

Cezar Joita showed that any domain is the projection of a pseudoconvex domain. See his paper On projections of pseudoconvex domains  Math Zeit vol 233 (2000) 625-631 .